# Will site work OK if I use microdata on non HTML5 site?

Tags: html, microdata, rich-snippets

I want to implement the microdata on my site which is not using HTML5 yet, it uses

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I'm planning to convert it to HTML5 soon. But for now I need to implement rich snippets, some simple things like for example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"> 
  Come hear the <span itemprop="name">Tiny Tim Tribute Band</span> in
  <span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"> 
    <span itemprop="name">Regency Theater</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Of course it will not validate in W3C validator. But **are there any other problems** that I should expect? Will my site render correctly in modern browsers? And what about older browsers like IE7?

I want to emphasize that this is only a temporary solution and site will be soon converted to HTML5.

Comment: By saying your site is not yet HTML5 what do you mean? Do you mean it still has the HTML4 Doctype or that it will run in browsers that do not yet support HTML5?

Comment: You could use RDFa (which can be used in various HTML versions) instead of Microdata (which is only defined for HTML5).

Comment: @unor In this case Microdata is required in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Put in short - as long as you use recognizable tags, IE7 will not have any problems, regarding the newer browsers - they have no issues, even if they do not recognize some tag.

So if you plan to use only `div` and `span` - you'll be fine, attributes and values are irrelevant, because even older browsers have fool-proof logic that workarounds this matter and can handle it.